# Query to retrieve tags and organize by most popular

Tags: mysql, laravel

I build a blog. On my blog, I would like to get my tags but I would like to sort them by more used. I have a pivot table and I don't know how to deal with it at all.

I have a table 'tags', a table 'articles' and a table 'article_tag'.

[image]

Can you show me how it is possible to carry out such an operation with the QueryBuilder?

Thank you

Comment: can you add sample data from database ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOIN, GROUP BY and COUNT:

```
$tags = Tags::join('article_tags as at', 'at.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')
    ->groupBy('tags.id')
    ->selectRaw('tags.*, count(*) as article_count')
    ->orderBy('article_count', 'desc')
    ->get();
```